# Binding dictionary to Accordion panes

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an Accordion control with several panes.

On page load I want to set controls inside the panes with data from dictionary (every pane has from 1 to 10 controls).

---

ASPX

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"
               FadeTransitions="True"
               SelectedIndex="0"
               HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
               ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
               Width="370px">
    <Panes>
        <cc1:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
            <Header>
                some text
            </Header>
            <Content>              
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"
                           Text='<%# Eval("key1")%>'></asp:Label></li>             
            </Content>
        </cc1:AccordionPane>     
        <cc1:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server">
            <Header>
                some text
            </Header>
            <Content>              
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"
                           Text='<%# Eval("key2")%>'></asp:Label></li>             
            </Content>
        </cc2:AccordionPane>      
    </Panes>            
</cc1:Accordion>
```

---

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("key1", "XXXXXXXXXX");
    dic.Add("key2", "YYYYYYYYYY");

    Accordion1.DataSource = dic;
    Accordion1.DataBind();
}
```

**Update:**

This is an example of a  dictioanry that I want to bind to accordion:

```
 var dic = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>();
        dic.Add("Item1", new List<object>() //This to Pane 1
                { 
                    new { SNumber = 12345 },
                    new { Color = "Blue" },
                    new { Size = "Large" },
                });
        dic.Add("Item2", new List<object>() //This to Pane 2
                { 
                    new { SNumber = 1235678 },
                    new { type = "OM" }
                });
        Accordion1.DataSource = dic;
        Accordion1.DataBind();
    }
```

On aspx, I want to create Pane for every section (in this case 2 panes), and in every pane define Eval for needed value.

p.s.
I don't think it metters but if dictionary binding is a problem I can bind something else like xmldocument or so...

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are interested in binding dictionary values to the accordion. To take advantage of data binding, you should use the control's templates instead of explicitly defining the accordion panes. For example:

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"
               FadeTransitions="True"
               SelectedIndex="0"
               HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
               ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
               Width="370px">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <h2><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Key") %>' /></h2>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>' /></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</cc1:Accordion>
```

---

Now, if your dictionary values are complex objects, which may be true since you describe having multiple controls in your content, you can still bind to the dictionary. Consider the slightly-more-involved dictionary below. For simplicity in demonstration, the dictionar values are simple matching anonymous types:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dic.Add("key1", new { Color = "Red", Age = 15 });
    dic.Add("key2", new { Color = "Green", Age = 25 });

    Accordion1.DataSource = dic;
    Accordion1.DataBind(); 
}
```

You can "chase down" the properties in your data binding expressions with an accordion configured like so:

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"
               FadeTransitions="True"
               SelectedIndex="0"
               HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
               ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
               Width="370px">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <h2><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Key") %>' /></h2>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value.Color") %>' /></div>
        <div><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value.Age") %>' /></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</cc1:Accordion>
```

Notice that the only important difference is the dot-notation in the `Eval` statements.

---

If, on the other hand, the dictionary value is (or contains) a *collection* of objects, it is a small matter to embed more advanced ASP.NET controls in your content template. Consider the following dictionary:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>();
dic.Add("key1", new List<object>()
                { 
                    new { Color = "Red" },
                    new { Color = "Blue" }
                });
dic.Add("key2", new List<object>()
                { 
                    new { Color = "Yellow" },
                    new { Color = "Orange" }
                });
```

Suppose the intent is to present each of the colors within the same content area. This can be accomplished by databinding the dictionary value to a repeater, like so:

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"
               FadeTransitions="True"
               SelectedIndex="0"
               HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
               ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
               Width="370px">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <h2><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Key") %>' /></h2>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Value") %>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Color") %>' /></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</cc1:Accordion>
```

---

Happy coding!

Comment: it's not what I need. I want to have multiple values in one pane. Contentetemplate allows just one value per pane.

Comment: @asker: the question as posted does not have multiple values per dictionary key. You might consider revising your question if your needs are actually different. Note that the solution I provided allows for the presentation of multiple pieces of data, provided the data are properties of the value. I updated my post to reflect an additional approach, useful when binding dictionary values that are actually *collections* of objects instead of individual objects. I hope this helps.

Comment: this why I aked how to bind data to accordionpane, I have about 10 panes(every pane is a category, or a "collection") and in every pane about 10 fields to bind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest data bound controls.

The top level is your accordion - that gets bound to the dictionary.

The content for the accordion panels is then another data bound control - not entirely sure what's appropriate in this case - that you want to bind to the list that is the dictionary value.

This is probably most easily done using the OnDataBound event (assuming there is one) for the accordion panel.

I'm not in a position to provide a worked example at this point.